# При вставке в таблицу MS SQL ошибка "Ошибка при преобразовании типа данных varchar к float".

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql

Делаю так:

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO [Table] ( name, [datetime], f1, f2, stat, data) VALUES ( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}' );";
sqlString = String.Format(sqlString, name, dt, single1, single2, stat, data.ToString());
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnect);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

На строку

```
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

выдаёт

```
Ошибка при преобразовании типа данных varchar к float.
```

При попытке выполнить содержимое **sqlString** после вставки в неё данных *String.Format* в Microsoft SQL Server Manager Studio выдаётся та же самая ошибка.

Как записать правильно преобразовать Single (float) для вставки в MS SQL Server ?

Comment: А можно привести схему таблицы Table?

Comment: Может быть не стоит заключать числовые значения в апострофы (mssql под рукой нет). Другой вариант причины -- разные локали (разделитель -- точка или запятая).

Ещё возможный метод лечения -- использовать property .Parameters для SqlCommand. В Вашем случае sqlString.Parameters

Comment: @alexlz [SQL Fiddle][1] под руку mssql, oracle и некоторые другие. Не к этому вопросу, just FYI.

[1]:http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Спасибо. Буду знать.

Comment: Действительно, замена запятой точкой помогла, спасибо.

Comment: Может всё-таки лучше .Parameters? А замена запятой на точку -- это шаманство. А вдруг и сервер решит, что он в России?

Comment: Я сразу пробовал **.Parameters**, но не помогло - ошибка все равно выскакивал.  
Возможно от того что MS SQL Server 2008 редакции Express, а может ещё почему.

Comment: Мелкомягкие наврали в API? (Не винды у меня...)

Comment: Не понятно, но все что я пробовал (кроме ручной замены , на . ) не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо сделать преобразование типа в запросе + ,как сказал [[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz), у Вас, возможно, не совпадают локали и формируемые в запрос числа идут скажем с запятой вместо точки:

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO [Table] ( name, [datetime], f1, f2, stat, data) VALUES ( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', cast('{3}' as float), cast('{4}' as float), '{5}' );";
sqlString = String.Format(sqlString, name, dt, single1, single2, stat, data.ToString());
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnect);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

если это тоже упадёт с ексепшеном, то надо играться с локалью. Так же попробуйте числа без кавычек в запрос впихнуть.

А какой текст запроса у вас для параметрического вызова?

Попробуйте для перевода числа в строку использовать такой код:

```
var strNumber = number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Текст такой как я привел, а типы переменных следующие:

    String name, stat;
    DateTime datetime;
    Single single1, single2;
    Int16 data;
    
Все равно ругается, что не может преобразовать varchar в float. Видимо придется таки браться за локали... Если ни кто больше не подскажет решения.

Comment: Так для параметров надо же аля:

    sqlString = "INSERT INTO [Table] ( name, [datetime], f1, f2, stat, data) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? );";

и параметры без ToString-ов, хотя мне кажется что он один хрен потом их преобразует в SQL и видимо по текущей локали. Так что надо узнать локаль скуеля и пропихивать в нужной оперируя Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

Comment: Так и сделал, спасибо :)

Comment: А как именно? С параметрами прошло или с локалями?

Comment: Помогли только локали, с параметрами фикус не прошел - все так же ругается, что не может преобразовать varchar к float.  
Не любит он запятые в качестве разделителей - точки ему подавай.

Comment: я так понимаю, float - это поля f1 и f2? зачем же тогда передавать их в виде строки. Пишете тип параметра sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@f1", SqlDbType.Float); передаете значение параметра в запрос sqlCommand.Parameters["@f1"].Value = Double.Parse(single1);